# How do pass data from a modal with a form on, to the home page?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am trying to pass data from the form on the model back to the home page an output on the screen. I have tried ngModel but can't seem to get it working correctly.

tasks.component.html

```
<form  class="well" (submit)="addTask($event)">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="ADD TASK">
</div>
</form>
```

tasks.component.ts

```
import {Component, enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
import {TaskServices} from "../app/services/task.services";
import {Task} from "../../Task";
enableProdMode();
@Component({
selector: 'tasks',
templateUrl: './tasks.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./tasks.component.css']
})
export class TasksComponent {
tasks: Task[];
name:string;

constructor(private taskServices:TaskServices){
  this.taskServices.getTasks()
      .subscribe(tasks =>{
         console.log(tasks);
        this.tasks = tasks;
      });
 }
 addTask(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 console.log(this.name);
 }

 title = 'app';
 }
```

Task.ts

```
 export class Task{
name:string;
}
```

i have written the addTask event here when i submit the form the input field data should be print in console.

But the form was not submitting when i enter data in input field and press enter the form was not submitting.

when i remove the addTask() in .ts file and when i type some data(i.e data1) in input field and by clicking enter then the form is submitting.And the url look like
http://localhost:4200/?name=data1

why it is happened and how to submit the form  data to the addTask()  and to be printed in console?

Comment: your code working for me

Comment: @durga it the form this small with only one field or it has other fields too

Comment: take a look at this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Wjlp4VYiNzPS0m6Z3jG8) , more on [ template forms](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/template) & [reactive](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/template)